# Flash Builder APK is not installable manually

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have a strange issue, if I debug or run my android application from Flash Builder i can get all working properly, even installation on device.
When i try to install manually the APK file, my apk installer can't see the package correctly, but is the same installed by Flash Builder on device.
Cetificate is right and everything runs without errors.

If i publish APK from FLASH IDE the package si visible correctly and i can install it manually using APK installer.

What am I missing in FLASH BUILDER to export correct APK ?

THank u all in advance.